# Angular FormAray of compnent

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, angular2-formbuilder, angular-formbuilder

I'm trying to do a an array of the child component reactive form. every time I edit in the child (questionForm) it get updated in the parent (adminForm), I have been trying to do this for 2 weeks. so please if you can help I appreciate it I left some related code from what I've been working on

parent.ts

```
 this.adminForm=this.fb.group({
      //SurveyName:this.nameForm.getData(),
      Questions: this.fb.array([
      ])
    });

get questions() {
    return this.adminForm.controls["Questions"] as FormArray;
  }
addQuestion() {
    //this.questions.push();
  }
```

parent.html

```
<div *ngFor="let alias of questions.controls; let i=index">
            <app-question></app-question>
</div>
 <a (click)="addQuestion()">Add question</a>
```

child.ts

```
this.questionForm = this.fb.group({
      question: [''],
      type: ['Checkboxes'],
      required: [false],
      options: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control('')
      ])
    });
```

Comment: Can you please simulate it in stackbliz so that it is easy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use a child to control a FormGroup, there are two aproach:

1. Create the formGroup in parent and pass to child using `@Input`
2. Create the formGroup in child and pass to parent using `@Output`

For me is more confortable using the first aproach

If you has in your parent

```
getGroup(){
  return this.fb.group({
      question: [''],
      type: ['Checkboxes'],
      required: [false],
      options: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control('')
      ])
    });
}
//when add a question, always in parent
addQuestion() {
  this.questions.push(this.getGroup());
}
```

Your child simply has

```
formGroup:FormGroup;
@Input('form') set form(value){
    this.formGroup=value as FormGroup
}
```

the hml like another formGroup

```
   <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
     <input formControlName="question">
     ....
   </form>
```

And you use in parent:

```
<div *ngFor="let alias of questions.controls; let i=index">
     <app-question [form]=questions.at(i)></app-question>
</div>
```