# Type AbstractControl is not assignable to type FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `FormGroup` with `FormArray` control filled with `FormGroup` instances

```
  someForm = this.fb.group({
    days: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        description: ['']
      })
    ])
  })
```

also, I have a getter for this array

```
  get days(): FormArray {
    return this.someForm.get('days') as FormArray;
  }
```

when I'm trying to iterate through `FormArray` and assign it to `[formGroup]` directive, like shown in [this article](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a)

```
 <div *ngFor="let day of days.controls">
  <ng-container [formGroup]="day">
    ...
```

I'm getting

```
error TS2740: Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround in [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields#:%7E:text=FormArray%20is%20used%20to%20track,or%20even%20other%20FormArray%20instances.), to iterate through `FormGroups` by `index` like:

```
 <div *ngFor="let day of days.controls; let i=index">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
         ...
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution. BTW. `*ngFor="let day of days.controls"` actually **not** work (I think that it's not allowed from Angular 9 -check when the articles are writting-)

Answer (score 12):

Another workaround would be to use casting in the component.

template:

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="getFormGroup(day)">
```

component:

```
getFormGroup(control: AbstractControl) { return control as FormGroup; }
```

So that we can still utilize the control as input value to components looped in the ngFor for formArray

> ```
> <ng-container *ngFor="let day of days.controls">
>     <childComponent [formGroup]="day"></childComponent>
> </ng-container>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Here, this is how I solved my issue. This approach is useful when you had to pass the formGroup to the child component also

Template:

```
<ng-container formArrayName="days" *ngFor="let day of days;>
  <form [formGroup]="day"></form>
</ng-container>
```

Component:

```
  get days(): FormGroup[] {
       const formArray = this.someForm?.get('days') as FormArray;
       return formArray.controls as FormGroup[];
    }
```

here I return the controls from getter as FormGroup[]

Comment: From Angular 9 you should use `<div *ngFor="let day of days.controls;let i=index"><ng-container [formGroupName]="i">...</bg-container></div>`. See that use `[formGroupName]` with the index of the variable

Comment: Hii @Eliseo, Thanks got it. I used this approach because I had to pass the formGroup instance to the child form field component. I'm on angular 13 and started learning angular very recently.

Comment: if you has a child component, really your aproach is ok. Well, I like more use the "input like a getter, see e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66684963/angular-formaray-of-compnent/66688173#66688173) or use `{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective },` like this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72107620/how-to-add-controls-to-a-sub-form-in-child-component-using-formgroupdirective/72111040#72111040)